# Is it a bad practice to load javascript files inside of Literals? (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, literals

It seems rather convenient. I was wondering if there was a good reason to load one of the RegisterScript methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RegisterScript methods can be used without placing any markup in the page, and without knowing the specific type of the page. Also, you can add the same script more than once, and it will only be included once in the page.

This is convenient when you want to include script from a user control, as you then can use the control in different pages, and more than once in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't recall RegisterScript methods working on pages without a `<form runat="server">...</form>`.  That bit me once.  In those cases, using literals or placeholders is not a particularly bad option.  The other options I can think of is to make sure the `head` tag (or some other useful tag) has runat="server" and then dynamically add to it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are trying to achieve. Do you really need to generate the javascript dynamically? You could just create a separate js file and reuse that.

As with the **RegisterScript** methods you can control where you want to place the javascript. For example with **RegisterStartupScript**, it registers your script at the end of the page (helps perceived performance and ensure that all objects have been loaded)

If you use literal controls, you might have to remember to but it at the end or top of page.